# Try Catch null and empty array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, null, try-catch

I am trying to perform a catch of exception in a method I made:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
        if (array.length == 1) {
            return array;
        }
        int[] arrayToSort = array.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length - 1; i++) {
            int minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayToSort.length; j++) {
                if (arrayToSort[j] < array[i]) {
                    if (arrayToSort[j] < arrayToSort[minIndex])
                        minIndex = j;
                }
            }
            if (i != minIndex) {
                Swap.selectionSwap(arrayToSort, minIndex, i);
            }
        }
        return arrayToSort;
    }
```

I want to validate and catch an exception for :
1) array lenght equal 0 
2) null inside the array

I tried to do this at the beggining of my method:

```
      try {
        if(array.length == 0);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exceptionForAnEmptyArray) {
        System.out.println("an array need to be filled");
    }
    try {
           array.equals(null);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("An array should contain the numbers");
    }
```

The empty array went through validation but message didn't appeared. Same with the null. Tried to parse null using Inter.parseInt inside the array. How do I need to modify the try catch to diplay message on the screen whenever the exception occours ?

Comment: at first of your method use this: if (array == null). You can not call array methods like .length and .empty when it is already null.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how it works. If you want to do something in response to an expression being true, exceptions aren't relevant and won't help you. Try something like:

```
if (array.length == 0) System.out.println("An array need to be filled");
```

Alternatively, just do your thing then respond to the problem AFTERward - the statement that causes the problem goes in the try, and there is no need for a checking expression:

```
try {
    System.out.println("The first item is " + array[0]);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("An array need to be filled");
}
```

Here the `array[0]` expression, upon being executed, would throw that exception. Because it happens within a try block, execution jumps to the matching catch block.

Comment: I think you did not understand what Jakub wanted to achieve, anyway your answer is totally correct (now) and describes how we usually catch exceptions, therefore I voted with +1.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `if(array.length == 0);` checks if the length is zero but does nothing then. You possibly wanted to write:

```
try {
    if (array == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("the array is null");
    }
    if (array.length == 0) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("the array is empty");
    }

    // process the content of the array here

} 
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot process the array because:");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This would also cover other exceptions that may occur while processing the content.

However, the `NullPointerException` would be generated automatically as soon you attempt to access the content of the array, which would be the `array.length` call in your case.

Also the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would be generated automatically if you attempt to access an array-index which does not exist. But if the array is empty, then no error will occur because your for-loop will not be executed. `i=0` is already larger than `arrayToSort.length-1`, before the loop starts.

Comment: Thx Stefan(dzięki?). You made very good point at the way the method might work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
    if(array == null) throw new NullPointerException("nullptr");
    if(array.length == 0) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("length equals 0");

    if (array.length == 1) {
        return array;
    }
    int[] arrayToSort = array.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length - 1; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayToSort.length; j++) {
            if (arrayToSort[j] < array[i]) {
                if (arrayToSort[j] < arrayToSort[minIndex])
                    minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != minIndex) {
            Swap.selectionSwap(arrayToSort, minIndex, i);
        }
    }
    return arrayToSort;
}
```

I'm not sure what else you might be after.